# Shadows in Metal, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, shader, metal

I’m creating 2d animation using Metal and LiquidFun. I want to simulate petrol. I want my animation to be yellow with gray shadows, similar to this:

[image]

Here is my current animation, it's totally yellow without any gray shadows, so it doesn't look realistic:

[image]

My fragment shader is very simple now, I only pass yellow color to it:

```
 fragment half4 fragment_shader(VertexOut in [[stage_in]],
                               float2 pointCoord [[point_coord]]) {
    float4 out_color = float4(0.7, 0.5, 0.1, 0.07);
    return half4(out_color);
};
```

I’ve checked various tutorials about adding shadows on MTKView, but they all suggest things that don’t work for me. The first thing that doesn’t work is creating various vertexes and setting color for each of them. In my code, I don’t have definite vertexes, I have a particle system which I pass to the vertex buffer:

```
   particleCount = Int(LiquidFun.particleCount(forSystem: particleSystem))
   let positions = LiquidFun.particlePositions(forSystem: particleSystem)
   let bufferSize = MemoryLayout<Float>.size * particleCount * 2
   vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: positions!, length: bufferSize, options: [])
```

Another thing I’ve tried is setting ambient, diffuse and specular colors, but it also didn’t work because my animation is 2D, not 3D.

I’ve also tried setting color based on particle position. My code inside fragment shader was close to this:

```
   if (in.position.y < 1500.0) {
        out_color = float4(0.7, 0.5, 0.1, 0.07);
   } else if (in.position.y > 1500.0) {
       out_color = float4(0.6, 0.5, 0.1, 0.07);
   }
```

But it also didn’t work as expected: color transitions were not smooth, it didn’t look like shadows. Plus my animation is increasing, so setting color to definite positions was not a good idea.

Could you please suggest something? I feel like I’m missing something very important.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you are trying to do and what doesn't work from this description

Comment: I've added some details to my question. Briefly, I want my Metal animation to be not completely yellow, but yellow with gray shadows.

Comment: Is the look you are trying to achieve similar to a 2D projection or is there "depth" to it? Not the depth below the surface, I mean the 3D depth. Anyway, on the picture above, I think the depth below the surface affects how yellow the thing is. If you aren't doing any weird projections, that would be the y axis in your thing. You could try blending the result with gray color based on how much the y differes from the "surface" level where your bubbles end.